# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(8n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Evaluate $$S=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(8n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$

I tried to use L'Hospital's Rule:

$$\ln(S)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\ln \left(8n-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

But how to differentiate $(-1)^n$, Should we assume two cases for even and odd $n$?

Comment: Do you already know $\lim n^{1/n}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\ln n \leq n$, we have
$$
\left\lvert\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\ln \left(8n-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{n^2}\ln(8n) \leq \frac{1}{n^2}(8n)=\frac{8}{n}.$$
Now just use [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: That’s of course a more effective way!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: given that $(-1)^n$ is just a matter of the sign, can you try to solve it assuming $1$ and see if it matters?

Answer (score 2):

We have that

- for $n$ even

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(8n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(8n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty}(8n)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{8n^2}\right)^\frac{1}{n^2}\to 1 \cdot 1=1$$

- for $n$ odd

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(8n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(8n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-\frac{1}{n^2}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{\left(8n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-\frac{1}{n^2}}}\to 1
$$

therefore

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(8n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\exp\left [\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \ln(8n) + \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \ln \left(1-1/(8n^2)\right)\right]=\exp\left [\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (-1)^n \frac{\ln(8n)}{n^2} \right].$$ By L'Hospital Rule, we get $$L=\exp\left [\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{2n^2}\right]=e^0=1.$$